# Bbox For Image Grabbing

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, webbrowser-control, pyautogui

So , I'm Trying To Make A Automated App

Actually , i'm making it for Dino Web Game

Everything Is Fine , But !
Colors Array's Number Will Not Change , I Think It is Boxing Problem

Can You Guide Me With Correct Values In This Box ?

```
from PIL import ImageGrab, ImageOps
from webbrowser import open_new_tab as new
from pyautogui import keyDown
from time import sleep
from numpy import *

site_url = "https://trex-runner.com/"
dinasour = (692, 494)


def pressSpaceButton():
    sleep(0.007)
    keyDown('space')
    
      
def openGamePage(): # Open Game URL In New Tab
    new(site_url)


def restartGame(): # Press Space Button To Start/Restart Game
    keyDown('space')
    print("Game Has Been Started / Restarted")


def FindCactuses(): # Find Cactuses In Screen
    box = ( #(top_left_x, top_left_y, bottom_right_x, bottom_right_y)
        dinasour[0] + 30,
        dinasour[1],
        dinasour[0] + 120, 
        dinasour[1] + 2   
    )
    image = ImageGrab.grab(box)
    grayImage = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
    a = array(grayImage.getcolors())
    print(a)
    return a.sum()

    
sleep(3) # Wait 3 Seconds
openGamePage()

sleep(5)# Wait 5 Seconds
restartGame()

  
while True:  
    FindCactuses()
    if FindCactuses != 697:
        pressSpaceButton()
```

It's Going To Recognize Black And White Colors And When It Finds A Black Color
it will press Space Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to pixel match a certain rgb value in a certain x,y position then you can use `pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(x, y, (r, g, b))` which is perfect for this situation

So in your code (keep in mind you will have to change the x,y values):

```
while True:
    #if at x 497 and y 524 the pixel matches your rgb color value of 83,83,83 then
    if pyautogui.pixelMatchesColor(497, 524,  (83, 83, 83)):
    #press up
    pyautogui.press('up')
```